# Contemporary resources for holographic superconductivity

Tags: resource-recommendations, superconductivity, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I am looking for more recently-written works (either major papers or review articles) on holographic superconductivity, preferably from 2019 or 2020. The main reviews I know are the following:

[Sean A. Hartnoll, Christopher P. Herzog, Gary T. Horowitz, "Holographic Superconductors" (2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1563)

[Gary T. Horowitz, "Introduction to Holographic Superconductors" (2010)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.1722)

[Rong-Gen Cai, Li Li, Li-Fang Li, Run-Qiu Yang, "Introduction to Holographic Superconductor Models" (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00437)

These are very good reviews (and they similarly list a large quantity of references), but I would prefer more contemporary major works or reviews. I would also be interested to see any more recent experimental confirmation of the holographic predictions.

Answer (score 2):

I found particularly useful chapter 10 of the [Zaanen et al. book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/holographic-duality-in-condensed-matter-physics/ED1E01756C18AE0352269202C31FE2B3) where several applications of the holographic superconductivity are discussed. However, this is a 2015 Ref.

I am really interested in this topic and following the developments of your question.

Answer (score 2):

The study of condensed matter systems using holography (AdS/CFT) is often referred to as AdS/CMT, holographic superconductors being one topic in this subfield. There is now a textbook called "Holographic Quantum Matter" by Hartnoll, Lucas, and Sachdev. The free arXiv preprint version is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07324). If you wanted to find very recent papers on this particular topic, you could use inspire-HEP to find papers citing the references above, e.g. [papers citing 0810.1563.](https://inspirehep.net/literature?sort=mostrecent&size=25&page=1&q=refersto%3Arecid%3A798954)

It's worth mentioning that in the past decade this area has slowed down and there are fewer papers and people working on it. But related topics have come up the context of AdS$_2$  and the SYK model, a solvable model of strongly-interacting Majorana fermions which seems to be dual to 2d black holes (more precisely, dilation gravity in AdS${}_2$). For instance, versions of the SYK model (often coupled SYK clusters) have been used to study non-Fermi liquids/strange metal phases. (I can add links/refs if this is of interest)